# Creating a text and dropdown list search functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I've written a piece of code that allows a Sharepoint list user to select a search criteria from a drop down list. By default, next to this, I'd like a textbox to be present. Besides the text box on the page is a Search button and a Reset button. This looks like this:

[image: Picture]

Ideally, what I'd like is that if the user selects a specific option in the search criteria drop down list (say, Field 3), the text box will change to a drop down list, which they choose their option from and then search for as usual.

This is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function RedirectUrl() { 
        var sField = document.getElementById("searchField").value;

        if (sField == "Field3") {
        var search = document.getElementById("dropdownSearch").value;
        } else {
        var search = document.getElementById("textSearch").value;
        }
    var url = "";

    if (search != "") {
        url = "FilterName=" + sField + "&FilterMultiValue=*" + search + "*";
        window.location.href = //Url of our site
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
} 

function ClearUrl() {
    //Refresh page
}

</script>
&nbsp;
Search Field: <select id="searchField">
<option selected value="Field1" >Field 1</option>
<option value="Field2">Field 2</option>
<option value="Field3">Field 3</option>
<option value="Field4">Field 4</option>
</select>

if (searchField == "Field3") {
  Search text: <select id="dropdownSearch" />
  <option selected value="One" >One</option>
  <option value="Two">Two</option>
  </select>
} else {
  Search text: <input type="text" id="textSearch" />
}
</script>

<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="return   RedirectUrl();" />
<input type="button" id="btnClear" value="Reset Filters" onclick="return ClearUrl();" />
```

The functionality of this code works. If the user selects "Field3" from the search field drop down list, whatever is selected in the drop down list is shown. If the user selects any other option from the search field drop down list, the text in the "search text" field is shown.

However, due to the if statement contained within, it looks like this:

[image: Picture 2]

**Questions:**

1. How can I get the code to *automatically* display either the text box **or** the drop down list depending on the user's selection in the Search Field?
2. How can I hide the if statement logic?

As can probably be guessed from the code I have almost zero experience in Javascript (and absolutely zero experience in JQuery, if any answers tend that way) - although I have tagged JQuery as from what little I do know I feel it might be better(?) suited for it.

**Edit: My not-working code after ZiNNED's help:**

```
Search Field:
<select id="searchField">
    <option selected value="Field1">Field 1</option>
    <option value="Field2">Field 2</option>
    <option value="Field3">Field 3</option>
    <option value="Field4">Field 4</option>
</select>Search Text:
<select id="dropdownSearch" style="display: none;">
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>
<input id="textSearch" />
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="link-to-Sharepoint/SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.1.js">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("change", "#searchField", function () {
        var show = $(this).val() == "Field3";
        $("#dropdownSearch").toggle(show);
        $("#textSearch").toggle(!show);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do a couple of things.
First: remove the `if`-statement from the code and hide the `dropdownSearch` select by default:

**HTML**

```
Search Field: <select id="searchField">
<option selected value="Field1" >Field 1</option>
<option value="Field2">Field 2</option>
<option value="Field3">Field 3</option>
<option value="Field4">Field 4</option>
</select>
Search text: 
<select id="dropdownSearch" style="display: none;" />
  // All options and their values
</select>"
<input type="text" id="textSearch" />
```

Second, add a reference to jQuery and the following JavaScript to your document:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("change", "#searchField", function () {
        var show = $(this).val() == "Field3";
        $("#dropdownSearch").toggle(show);
        $("#textSearch").toggle(!show);
    });
});
```

This adds an event to the `searchField` dropdown that triggers when its value is changed. If the value equals `Field3` the `dropdownSearch` is shown; otherwise the `textSearch`.

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcp8pbL3/)**.

EDIT: After your edit, try changing the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="link-to-Sharepoint/SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.1.js">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("change", "#searchField", function () {
        var show = $(this).val() == "Field3";
        $("#dropdownSearch").toggle(show);
        $("#textSearch").toggle(!show);
    });
});
</script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="link-to-Sharepoint/SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("change", "#searchField", function () {
        var show = $(this).val() == "Field3";
        $("#dropdownSearch").toggle(show);
        $("#textSearch").toggle(!show);
    });
});
</script>
```

You shouldn't add JavaScript to `script` tags when you're also referring to an external file in it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I see what it's meant to do, but I'm having an issue with it. The if statement is removed and the search functionality works perfectly for Field 1, 2 and 4. However, changing to "Field3" isn't hiding the textbox and showing the drop down list. I've added your JQuery script at the bottom of the page, surrounded by a <script type="text/javascript" src="link-to-source"> at the top and </script> at the bottom. Otherwise, I'm doing exactly as you say. Any suggestions?

Comment: Am I perhaps using an out of date JQuery? I'm pointing to JQuery 1.7.2.

Comment: It should work with that version also. Is the HTML posted in the TS the original HTML? Are you using the same id's etc in your production code?

Comment: Is this because I'm doing this in Sharepoint? I've tried using this site: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select3 and have pasted in the exact HTML code in Fiddle, followed by <script type="text/javascript" src="correct-link-to-my-jquery">, followed by the Javascript code in fiddle, followed by </script>. In that site, the changeover doesn't work, just like on my Sharepoint page.

Comment: Are there some settings in Fiddle I'm not seeing? Or something silly I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I've added my code exactly as it stands to my question as an edit. That's what I'm trying to use.

Comment: @AndrewMartin I've edited my answer. I think your problem now lies in the fact you're including JavaScript code inside a `script` tag where you're also referring to an external file.